# Go to middle of line in Vim

Tags: vim

I know <kbd>0</kbd> goes to the beginning of a line and <kbd>$</kbd> goes to the end, but is there something for the middle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
:call cursor(0, len(getline('.'))/2)
```

Comment: This would be fairly useful if it were mapped, e.g:  :nnoremap gm :call cursor(0, len(getline('.'))/2)<cr>

Comment: virtcol('$')/2 is enough.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: Nice, but not exactly the best behavior when hard tabs are involved.

Comment: That's why I use virtcol instead of col. :). But indeed we should use | and not cursor(). BTW, len() won't give any better result. Moreover, len will give other troubles with multi-bytes characters.

Comment: Could someone point me in the right direction on how to get it to move forward half way through the REMAINDER of the line from the current position? This would preserve my sanity when I have really long crontab lines trying to tweak my pipeline.

Comment: Even better (for me personally anyway): jump half way through the REMAINDER of the line from the current position `nnoremap l :execute "normal! " . ((col("$")  - col(".") )/ 2) . "l"<CR>` (so you can press the same thing repeatedly to hone in on something far away).

Answer (score 11):

Typing `gm` would do it, but it moves by screen lines (see `:help gm`). In order to get it working with text lines, one can remap this command:

```
map gm :call cursor(0, virtcol('$')/2)<CR>
```

Comment: gm seems to move cursor to middle of screen, but if my line of text is shorter than the length of the screen, it doesn't take me to the middle. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: @teggy: I see. I modified my solution to remap gm to go to the middle of text line. As you can see, it combines solutions from ephemient and Luc Hermitte.

Comment: As ephemient pointed out, it still has an issue with hard tarbs as cursor() counts them as one character each. Moreover, it won't work with multi-bytes characters either.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that will respect hardtabs, and multi-bytes characters as well.

```
:exe 'normal '.(virtcol('$')/2).'|'
```

Answer (score 4):

`gM`

Like "g0", but to halfway the text of the line. With a count: to this percentage of text in the line. Thus "10gM" is near the start of the text and "90gM" is near the end of the text.

https://neovim.io/doc/user/motion.html#gM

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) is the best solution that I have found. Jumping exactly to the middle of the line is not very practical. You will most likely still need to move the cursor a few positions after moving to the middle. What if you could jump to a specific character? Many people just search for the character, then hit "next" until they reach it. This is slow. The Easy-motion plugin offers a better solution.

My favorite is `<leader><leader>s` then the character you want to jump to. Easy Motion replaces all matches with different letters for you to choose from. See the tutorial. Its a life-changing plugin...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use:

```
map g1 :call cursor(0, virtcol('$')/0)<CR>
map g2 :call cursor(0, virtcol('$')/4)<CR>
map g3 :call cursor(0, virtcol('$')/2)<CR>
map g4 :call cursor(0, virtcol('$')/3*2)<CR>
map g5 :call cursor(0, virtcol('$'))<CR>
```

To center vertically  0% - 25% - 50% - 75% - 100%

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lectus sapien, rutrum quis vestibulum vitae, fringilla ac nisi.
```

For example if you wanna go to the word 'adipiscing'. Then you press g2w (go 25% + one word).